# error in image_address and name insertion in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, user-registration

i use this code for insert data in mysql but it directly shows error
" Could not enter data: "......

else

```
        {

            $image=$_FILES['img']['name'];
            $tmp_name=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

            $path= "/var/www/html/uploads/".$image;
            if(move_uploaded_file($name,$path))

            {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO form1 ". "(fname,lname,username,password,age,email,branch,college,
            gender,image_p,) ". "VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$password','$age','$mail','$branch','$college','$gender','$image')";
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            }

            if(! $retval ) 
            {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Entered data successfully\n"."\n ";
            echo "you are now a registered user.";

            mysql_close($conn);
            }
```

Comment: echo your query and make sure this is correct.

Comment: Remove last `,` from `gender,image_p,)`

Comment: please comment echo query result

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO form1 (fname,lname,username,password,age,email,branch,college,
        gender,image_p) VALUES ('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$username."','".$password."','".$age."','".$mail."','".$branch."','".$college."','".$gender."','".$image."')";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$image=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$tmp_name=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$path= "/var/www/html/uploads/".$image;
move_uploaded_file($name,$path);

if(! $retval ){
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
    echo "Entered data successfully\n"."\n ";
    echo "you are now a registered user.";
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: what did you get by applying it?

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$path))
                {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO form1 ". "(fname,lname,username,password,age,email,branch,college,
                gender,image_p) ". "VALUES('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$username."','".$password."','".$age."','".$mail."','".$branch."','".$college."','".$gender."','".$image."')";
                $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                }

Comment: i think problem is in if loop please take a look.

Comment: problem i in your condition.
Firstly insert data then call the function `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/php/img/22222222.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/php/form_red.php on line 200

Comment: Give URL in your path not folder structure.